# Advantages of different ways to share Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, local-storage, web-worker, server-sent-events

I have an intranet web system that displays real-time information.
There are server-side processes that log assorted updates into a database.
Various web pages then use Ajax to ask for anything new every few seconds.
This is all standard stuff (think RSS...) and does work so far.

However ... If a user has several pages on display, this causes multiple Ajax requests -- each effectively asking for the same data. This does not hurt for a few users, but will not scale well.
So I want to have one request per user. There are many options:

1. stay with an Ajax process per page and accept the duplication
2. use Server-sent events in each page (i.e. have the browser do the worrying)
3. have the first page feed the updates into local storage and the other pages catch the "storage" events
4. move the Ajax into a web worker which posts messages to the pages
5. Have I missed an option?

Any thoughts please on the relative gain / pain of the different options?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker).

All your pages will subscribe to it and wait for it to transmit the resources:

Below is the code from a [live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1kmc2dh/) demo (StackSnippet null origined frames aren't allowed to run SharedWorkers.)

```js
const script_content = document.getElementById('worker-script').textContent;
const script_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ script_content ] ) );

// This should be the only one per page
const worker1 = new SharedWorker( script_url );
worker1.port.onmessage = (e) => console.log('worker1 received data', e.data);
// This would be an other page
const worker2 = new SharedWorker( script_url );
worker2.port.onmessage = (e) => console.log('worker2 received data', e.data);
```

```html
<script id="worker-script" >
    const ports = []; // we'll store all the connected ports here
    onconnect = e => { / everytime a process connects
      ports.push( e.ports[ 0 ] );
    };
    setInterval( () => {
        const rand = Math.random(); // fetched data
        // transmit it to all connected processes
        ports.forEach( port => port.postMessage( rand ) );  
      }, 1000
    );
</script>
```

---

---

The biggest problem with SharedWorker is the browser support. You won't be able to use it on Safari.

But we now have [the `BroadcastChannel` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) which allows to communicate across different processes on the same domain and which can be polyfiled quite easily thanks to the Storage event.

So you could try to set up a system which would do the same as the SharedWorker, but in a bit more complex way.

When the browser connects to one of your page, it tries to join the BroadcastChannel or creates it.

It first sends a message through the BroadcastChannel asking if there is someone connected.

- If there is nobody connected, then this process will be responsible for the fetchings.

  - Everytime it gets a response from the server, it will dispatch it to all other processes through the BroadcastChannel.
  - When the process is about to be killed (e.g in `onbeforeunload`), it tells the connected process to pick one as the new fetcher.
- Otherwise

  - [optional] It pushes itself in a list of heir
  - It waits for the fetcher to give the data through the BroadcastChannel.

[Here is a jsfiddle proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/Lksx98do/) since while StackSnippet weirdly are allowed to run BroadcastChannels, their null origin will make them unable to share with any instance... Open this link in several tabs and see how they all talk each others.

Here is the code of the fiddle anyway:

```js
const my_id = Math.random();
let I_am_the_master = false;
let connections = ["me"];
const master_timeout = ImDaMasta();

const channel = new BroadcastChannel('demo');

channel.onmessage = e => {
  console.log(e.data);
  switch (e.data.type) {
    case "newData":
      onnewdatareceived(e.data.data);
      break;
    case "disconnect":
      ondisconnect(e);
      break;
    case "connect":
      onconnect(e);
      break;
    case my_id:
      oninitresponse(e);
  }
};

channel.postMessage({
  type: 'connect',
  _id: my_id
});


onbeforeunload = e => {
  channel.postMessage({
    type: 'disconnect',
    index: connections.indexOf('me')
  });
}

// set ourselves as the master process
function ImDaMasta() {
  I_am_the_master = true;
  return setInterval(() => {
    const rand = Math.random();
    channel.postMessage({
      type: "newData",
      data: rand
    });
    log("I'm the master and did post", rand);
  }, 1000);
}
// when we receive new data from the master
function onnewdatareceived(data) {
  log("I'm a slave and received", data);
}
// when an other process disconnected
function ondisconnect(e) {
  connections.slice(e.data.index, 1);
  if (connections[0] === "me") {
    ImDaMasta();
  }
}
// when an other process connects
function onconnect(e) {
  connections.push('other');
  if (I_am_the_master) {
    channel.postMessage({
      type: e.data._id,
      connections
    });
  }
}
// when the master process handled our connection
function oninitresponse(e) {
  I_am_the_master = false;
  clearTimeout(master_timeout);
  connections = e.data.connections;
  connections[connections.length - 1] = "me";
}


// helper
function log(...args) {
  _log.textContent = args.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)).join(' - ');
}
```

```html
<pre id="_log"></pre>
```